# Weird DNS bug - external server resolves to internal IP

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-ec2, internal-dns, ssh-agent

I have a server that is hosted by my university. I have root access, but no control over network setup, firewall, etc. This server's DNS resolves to an internal IP here on campus (10.x.x.x), and an external IP outside campus.

I also have a few servers hosted at Amazon, and they mostly work well. However, one of them started to resolve the university server by its internal IP address. This causes problems, as 10.x.x.x on Amazon EC2 is someone else.

I have connected to the Amazon server with SSH agent forwarding a few times in the past, to access a Git repository on the university server.

Any idea what could cause this?

EDIT: Here's my /etc/resolv.conf

```
# Generated by dhcpcd for interface eth0
search ec2.internal
nameserver 172.16.0.23
```

Here's the output of `dig myserver.myuniversity.ca.`:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.8.1-P1 <<>> myserver.myuniversity.ca.
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 34470
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;myserver.myuniversity.ca.  IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
myserver.myuniversity.ca. 537586 IN A   10.43.x.x

;; Query time: 2 msec
;; SERVER: 172.16.0.23#53(172.16.0.23)
;; WHEN: Wed Nov 28 16:07:21 2012
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 60
```

Here's the expected output (on another Amazon server):

```
; <<>> DiG 9.8.1-P1 <<>> myserver.myuniversity.ca.
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 8045
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;myserver.myuniversity.ca.  IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
myserver.myuniversity.ca. 601733 IN A   x.x.239.1

;; Query time: 1 msec
;; SERVER: 172.16.0.23#53(172.16.0.23)
;; WHEN: Wed Nov 28 16:09:36 2012
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 60
```

Comment: Are you using the FQDN in all cases?  That'd be my first thought - not using the FQDN + domain suffixing on your connection.

Comment: What does the content of the `/etc/resolv.conf` file looks like on that server?

Comment: That's what I thought at first, but I didn't touch it:
      # Generated by dhcpcd for interface eth0
      search ec2.internal
      nameserver 172.16.0.23

Comment: I can't seem to format my previous comment...

Comment: Yeah, [tag:markdown-ate-your-baby].  Having said that, you should edit the contents of `/etc/resolv.conf` into your answer anyway, where the markdown's a little less... awful.

Comment: I do not understand the downvotes. THe question seems perfectly sensible. Upvoted.

Comment: It is not clear if the resolv.conf you posted is for the "correct" Amazon machine or the "bad" one. Both digs show they used the resolver 172.16.0.23. Is it true? What is this machine, something provided by Amazon?

Answer (score -1):

You can fix the IP address of your university server inside Amazon servers by changing /etc/hosts. Windows has the same file as i remember
It's a simple solution because it's not clear what's DNS Server of your DOMAIN

Comment: Yes, but other servers resolve the external IP just fine...

Comment: what is DNS of your domain? I mean who will be queried by external DNS's to resolve your IP address?

Comment: Bad idea. The OP should fix the problem, not work around it.